# No visible @interface for 'PHImageManager' declares the selector 'requestImageForAsset:targetSize:options:resultHandler:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, camera-roll, phimagemanager

Here I am trying to get thumbnail for asset and i am not able to do it :(
I am getting this error:

```
No visible @interface for 'PHImageManager' declares the selector 'requestImageForAsset:targetSize:options:resultHandler:'
```

I am trying to just add this code block:

```c
PHCachingImageManager *imageManager = [[PHCachingImageManager alloc] init];
      [imageManager requestImageForAsset: asset
                               targetSize: CGSizeMake(80, 80)
                                  options: nil
                            resultHandler: ^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
                              //do something here
      }];
```

into here(You can get the bigger picture here):
https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll/blob/7c269a837d095a2cb5f4ce13b54ab3060455b17f/ios/RNCCameraRollManager.m#L325

I am trying to get thumbnail from original asset.

Comment: This is a question for the PHCachingImageManager developers, not really an iOS question. In the code you link to, I see no definition at all for any method called requestImageForAsset. Why do you think your code is supposed to work? Where did  you get info that such a method exists to be called?

Comment: Thank you for comment.
I believe this question is for iOS development, since i am trying to improve iOS library for react native.
Secondly, I have edited the question, and i tried to add the code block to the code i have sent the link to.